# css drop down menu not working on hover

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a simple menu that when hover it will have a drop down menu. The code is working when testing in Fiddle but not working on IE when run the whole page locally. Can anybody help

(here's my code at fiddle)[http://jsfiddle.net/bACbW]

```
<DIV align="left" id="floating-menu"><FONT class="subheading">
<ul class="dropmenu">
    <li><a href="#">MAIN MENU</a>
<ul class="dropmenu">
<li>WELCOME</li>
<li>PERSONAL INFORMATION</li> 
</ul> 
     </li>
</ul>
</FONT></DIV>
```

general.css

```
    /* All UL */
    #floating-menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
    background: #FF0040;
}

/* All LI */
#floating-menu ul li {
        padding: 5px 10px;
        height: 30px;
        position: relative;

}

/* First Level LI */
#floating-menu>ul>li {
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 27px;
    text-aligh: center;
    color: #9c9c9c;
}


#floating-menu li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;

}


#floating-menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;

}

#floating-menu li li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;

}

#floating-menu li li:hover {
    background: #5e8ce9;
}

.dropmenu {
    _zoom:1;
}

.dropmenu:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: be specific In IE which version.  it is working in IE10 and 9 and please post the code here, fiddle is not substitute.

Comment: Welcome to the world of Internet Explorer terror

Comment: Just added the fiddle. the drop down menu is within a left_navigation.jsp which is embedded in index.jsp calling a general css file on index.jsp.

Comment: i'm using IE9 not working

Comment: Check the document mode in IE, press F12 and check, because working for me in IE9.

Comment: What exactly isn't working??

Comment: when i run the page in IE, it only show the Main Menu, no drop down when hover. When I run the page in Chrome, it shows the Main Menu and submenu together as list, nothing happen when hover.

Comment: Your fiddle works for me in IE9.  Possible to share the link?

Comment: hey user1671639, I followed your instruction to check out document mode on F12, it shows me the default document mode which is Quirks mode. And when I turned it to IE9 standards the drop down menu works! May I know what is it going to do with document mode and how to make it default as IE9 standards?

Comment: @YUKIML I have created a brief answer.  check it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejRM4/1/)** link here and below corrected CSS. Also tested in  Firefox, chrome, and ie 7, 8 and 9. It working properly.

```
#floating-menu {
    width:940px;
    padding:10px;
    *padding:5px 10px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px  solid green;
    background-color:#3D3A40;
    border:8px solid #fff;
    }   
#floating-menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height:30px;
    background: #FF0040;
    }
#floating-menu ul li {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    *float:left;
    }
#floating-menu ul li a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    padding:0 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
#floating-menu ul li:hover a {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#5e8ce9;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
#floating-menu ul li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:30px;
    background-color:#5e8ce9;
    width:200px;
    line-height:18px;
    }
#floating-menu ul li ul li {
    border-bottom:1px solid #91b3f7;
    display:block;
    *float:none;
    }
#floating-menu ul li ul li a {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#0066FF;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:5px 10px;
    }
#floating-menu ul li ul li a:hover,
#floating-menu ul li ul li a.active {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#0000FF;
    }
#floating-menu ul li:hover ul {
    display:block !important;
    }

.dropmenu {
    _zoom:1;
    }
```

Comment: Really appreciate.. this is looking very good for my site. May I know if user wants to display the menu vertically instead of the current one... which part of code should I change? Thanks!!!

Comment: See the link here http://jsfiddle.net/ejRM4/2/

#floating-menu ul {
list-style-type: none;
line-height:30px;
background:#FF0040;
width:200px;/*newly added*/
}
#floating-menu ul li ul {
display:none;
position:absolute;
left:200px;/*newly added*/
top:0;/*newly added*/
background-color:#5e8ce9;
width:200px;
line-height:18px;
}

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comments, your code works fine in IE9.

The reason, **press F12 to get developer tools** and change the `document type`.

As you said it is in Quirks mode

```
!--  Force IE to use the latest version of its rendering engine -->  
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

By telling IE to use the latest version of its rendering engine in your page.
Incase if your user has only IE8 browser?  This will certainly fails.

You can check this in [**MSDN Library**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Hope you understand.

Comment: @YUKIML I'm glad that I was able to help.